# How to implement nav bar using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement nav bar navigation using jQuery. But no luck! Please have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjWbP/56/).

My requirement is to active menu item based on content scrolled, and scrolling the content based on menu item clicked. Below is the code

```
$('.menu-item').on('click', function () {
    var that = $(this);
    $('.menu-item').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
    that.addClass('active');
    var index = that.index();
    var target = $('.menu .menu-target').eq(index);
    $('.right').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 500);
});

$('.right').on('scroll', function () {
    var scrTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
        tgt = "";
    $('.menu-target').each(function () {
        var th = $(this),
            offTop = th.offset().top;
        if (offTop > scrTop && && tgt === "") {
            tgt = th;
        }
    });

    if (tgt !== "") {
        var index = tgt.index();
        $('.menu-item').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $('.menu-item').eq(index).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

But this is not working. Updating active menu item on scroll is not working. How to fix this?

**Edit** 
Tried to fix the issue and here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/SfR2c/11/
It is working with some inconsistency in updating menu element based on scroll content!

Comment: Why not use Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: Why bootstrap if I can do it with jQuery with my own styling?

Comment: just gave a glance. it seems there is somethings wrong while doing `$('.right').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 500);`. it says `top` of undefined. check it out

Comment: `.menu-target` are not inside `.menu` !

Comment: @Exception Bootstrap uses jQuery and you can style it your own, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
 var target = $('.menu .menu-target').eq(index);
```

by this

```
 var target = $('.right .menu-target').eq(index);
```

Comment: AGILE matter ;) ... Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/f00bar/SfR2c/) Congrats, you now have a nice homemade component ! I changed some code at the bottom of 'scroll' handler as well

Comment: Thanks for the response! And my question was more into maintaing the exact menu item based on content scroll. Even though this issue is fixed, the mentioned issue is still exists. Could you please look into that.

Comment: All right, I did not get this detail. I will give a closer look and if I find what's missing, I will update the fiddle and let you know `;)`

Comment: Now It works ! Fiddle still be [THIS ONE](http://jsfiddle.net/f00bar/SfR2c/) Now have a look and if you need explanations then we will discuss through private messages

Comment: You are awesome dude! You did a great job. It will help so many people to reduce one dependency

Comment: I'm glad this helped you, feel free to contact if you have any question `;)`

Comment: Could you please contact me @svap.reddy@gmail.com if you are interested in some new stuff.

Answer (score -3):

there is already a working solution to your needs. when programming please DO reuse everything you can.

the solution is to use [Bootstrap from twitter ScrollSpy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)