# Changing text in navigation according to place

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, position

I need some help / guidence in how to solve my little problem.

I want my Navigation text to change accordingly to my position on the site. (position1, position2 etc.)

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iBertel/ah2zj/6/

i need the fixed-nav text to change to what ever position it is on.

EDIT: i have edit the fiddle, so it might makes more sense now.

**HTML**

```
<div class="page-wrap">
    <div class="fixed-nav">
        <span>Position 1</span>
    </div>

    <div id="position1" class="link">
        page 1
    </div>
    <div id="position2" class="link">
        page 2
    </div>
    <div id="position3" class="link">
        page 3
    </div>
    <div id="position4" class="link">
        page 4
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.page-wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.fixed-nav {
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}

.link {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border-top:1px solid #F20;
}
```

**JQUERY**

None yet - im really not sure how to start this.

Hope someone can help me out or guide me were i can find answer to this.

cheers and thank you for reading.

Comment: did not understand. can u explain exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to this?? - http://jsfiddle.net/4cWH3/5/

Comment: Im sorry for my poor explanation. Ill try to clarify:

I want my text in the fixed nav to change when i scroll down over the site. So if im on page 2 the fixed nav text should be position 2 as the ID. This makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete guesstimate, but it sounds like you want to change the content of your fixed nav, depending on where the user has scrolled to on the page?

If so, you could do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).scroll(function() {        
    if ($('body').scrollTop() > 600) {
      $('.fixed-nav span').text('Page 3+');
    } else if ($('body').scrollTop() > 200) {
      $('.fixed-nav span').text('Around page 2');
    } else {
      $('.fixed-nav span').text('Looking at page 1, ish.');
    }        
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ah2zj/4/

**Edit:**

If you have no idea what the height of each 'page' is going to be, you could do something like this instead

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
    $.each($('.link'), function (index, value) {
      var position = $(this).position();
      var top = position.top;
      var bottom = position.top + $(this).height();

      if ($('body').scrollTop() >= top && $('body').scrollTop() <= bottom) {
        $('.fixed-nav span').text($(this).attr('id'));
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ah2zj/7/

So what that does is every time the user scrolls on the page, it'll loop through every page element and determine their position on the page. If their position on the page is within the range of your scroll, it updates your nav with the id of that element.

**Edit:**

In case of Firefox being stupid, you'll need to do

```
var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ah2zj/8/

Comment: Im sorry for my poor explanation. Ill try to clarify:

I want my text in the fixed nav to change when i scroll down over the site. So if im on page 2 the fixed nav text should be position 2 as the ID. This makes sense?

Comment: @implum Depends if you know the height of each 'page' beforehand, if you do, it could simply be like http://jsfiddle.net/ah2zj/5/

Comment: I dont know heights, they are not the same of each one. - damn, didnt think this would be som complicated...

Comment: @implum It's not _that_ complicated :) I'll update my answer for you with a version that'll handle any height

Comment: This is exactly what i want - however the text doenst change in that fiddle?? Mine says position 1 alle the way down, it doesnt change to position 2 etc. when i pass the IDs

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. If you have an extra minute - can you tell me if its possible to have an offset to the top so it wont change untill the fixed-nav hits the top.

Comment: @implum sure, this line `var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();` you can simply change to something like  `var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop() + 95;` etc... and it'll give you some offset play around with it until you get the desired accuracy :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Have an A 1 day sir ;)!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood what you mean, and I think I already answered to a similar question

Don't you need something like this .. just have a look ta the fiddle attached:
[How to implement nav bar using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315835/how-to-implement-nav-bar-using-jquery/19316236#19316236)

Comment: Well this is a navgivation that changes, mine i need the text to change in the navigation. Somehow get the elements ID to be displayed once it is at top of page.